# Connect Robomongo to Virtual Machine

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I have a problem. I'm using Virtual Box with RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) and I've installed a MongoDB and an Oracle-XE database.

I'm trying to connect to my DBs from my Windows OS.
I can connect to my oracle DB using SQL Developer, however when trying to use Robomongo to connect to my MongoDB I can't connect. And I have no idea why.

I've specified port forwarding in both cases, why does one work and the other doesn't?

I've tryed the following:

```
address: localhost port: 27017
address: 127.0.0.1 port: 27017
address: mongo.localhost port: 27017
```

And others... Why can't I connect with Robomongo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In ubuntu I opended `\etc\mongod.conf`

I commented `bind_ip = 0.0.0.0` to `#bind_ip = 0.0.0.0`

And as you know, you should use `address: 192.168.0.105. port: 27017` (your linux ip; you can get Ip with command >$ `hostname -I`

Maybe same thing works for u in RedHat

Comment: Check firewall rules to not blocking 27017

Comment: That's not the problem, I have both firewalls (windows and RHEL) disabled

Comment: Worth mentioning is also that mongo has to be restarted after its config change, by command: `sudo service mongod restart`

Answer (score 2):

After comment the `bind_ip` in `\etc\mongod.conf` 
 
You need to do `port forwarding` in the VirtualBox setting. 
 
Typically your VirtualBbox IP would be something like `10.0.2.15` 
(confirm that with the command `hostname -I` in VM)

and suppose your host PC's IP is `192.168.1.234` 
(confirm that with the command `ipconfig` in host PC)

now open the settings for your VM
click `Network` -> `Port forwarding`

add something like:

Name      Protocol    HostIP               HostPort     GuestIP      GuestPort
Rule1      TCP          192.168.1.234    27017         10.0.2.15    27017
Rule2      TCP          192.168.1.234    80               10.0.2.15    80   (if you're hosting a web server)

now, intead of setting Robomongo's connecting IP=GuestIP
you should use `address: 192.168.1.234 port: 27017` 
then the virtualbox should now direct your request to the right place.